# markdown: list number with sub-text under each section

Tags: markdown

Is it possible to have a short description below a number list using markdown?

This works as expected (without description):

[image: ok]

Does not work (always number "1"):

[image: not ok 1]

Does not work (description align):

[image: not ok 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is:

```
1. one

   description

2. two

   description
```

Note the indent.

> 1. one
>
>    description
> 2. two
>
>    description

Comment: One space is enough (but it's not this pretty that way).

Comment: Well, the spacing between the paragraph in a list item and list items can be adjusted with CSS. That alone can make this look a lot better.